# Mask in Multiline TextBox

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I WOuld like to implement textBox in which user can only insert text in pattern like this:

```
dddddddddd,
dddddddddd,
dddddddddd,
...
```

where d is a digit. If user leave control with less then 10 digits in a row validation should fail and he should not be able to write in one line more than 10 digits, then acceptable should be only comma ",".

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

```
 Match m = Regex.Match(textBox.Text, @"^\d{10},$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Haven't tried it, but it should work. Please take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx) and [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) for more information.

Comment: And in TextBox control where should I set this ?

Comment: You should have some sort of button or other action driven component that launches the validation. For instance, a button named "continue" or "next" or something like that. It really depends on how you set up your flow.

Comment: This will return True if at least one line (but not necessarily all lines) follows this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the regex

```
\A(?:\s*\d{10},)*\s*\d{10}\s*\Z
```

**Explanation:**

```
\A        # start of the string
(?:       # match the following zero or more times:
 \s*      # optional whitespace, including newlines
 \d{10},  # 10 digits, followed by a comma
)*        # end of repeated group
\s*       # match optional whitespace
\d{10}    # match 10 digits (this time no comma)
\s*       # optional whitespace
\Z        # end of string
```

In C#, this would look like

```
validInput = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"\A(?:\s*\d{10},)*\s*\d{10}\s*\Z");
```

Note that you need to use a verbatim string (`@"..."`) or double all the backslashes in the regex.